# Stuck in Chrono Trigger with broken 'L' key

Tags: chrono-trigger

My DS's 'L' key is broken, and its 'R' is unreliable. I've been playing Chrono Trigger, and it's been fine up to now.

In Beyond the Ruins, a rat statue tells me a password, but it involves pressing 'L' and 'R' at the same time. Anyone know a workaround?

Comment: heh, I had the same problem, dropped my DS, totally ruined my R key, those things are so fragile.

Have you tried repairing your keys?  According to some research, blowing into the L and R keys can get them to work again for a short while.

Comment: borrow someone elses DS for a few minutes?

Comment: The blowing trick works for me. My L button stops working about once every two weeks but a puff of air always starts it going again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Here are your options:

#### Use someone else's DS

Borrow a friend's DS to get past this part and save your game.

If you don't know anyone with a DS, a used video game store would probably let you play your cartridge on a used DS for a few minutes without leaving the store.

#### Repair your DS

Ask your local used game store if they do repairs or who they use for repairs.

#### Get a new DS

Used ones aren't that much, especially if you get an older one.

Comment: Thanks! We wound up using a DS at Gamestop, specifically.

Comment: There's a part later in the game, when Luca is remembering a tragic event from her past.  You need L and R to successfully complete it.